# Why was Starlight vomiting?

Tags: plot-explanation, the-boys

Why was Starlight throwing up at the party in the episode 8 of season 1?

Comment: She was clearly drunk, and people usually vomit when they drink too much.

Comment: @Baku I watched it again, no drinking show but it was implied I guess with empty shots https://i.stack.imgur.com/KdqLY.png

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's implied that she was drunk; we see her speaking a bit slowly, flirting with a random guy and then there's this shot of many empty glasses on her table.

[image]

Shortly after this scene she excuses herself to the toilet and starts puking. It's a common depiction in TV / movies that means the character drank too much.

It's also a hook for the trope [Book-Ends](https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/BookEnds), since this matches the scene in the first episode where again Starlight and Maeve talk during a vulnerable moment in a toilet.

Comment: Because of the scene from episode one, I thought there might be other reasons why she was vomiting. Thanks for the clarification!